# Please give some suggestion with code for Best practices to be followed for Reactjs Select dropdown

Tags: reactjs

UI developer has given me a jquery plugin for select dropdown, the plugin creating the dropdown in div and hiding the select tag. Because styles can't be applied to Select option.

But I have written the validation for Select tag. There is a conflict between us.

So, please provide some best practices for writing Select dropdown option with custom css for React along with custom validation

Comment: You should add the codes you are comparing and ask a direct question about it. The way you describe your problem now it not very likely to be solved. StackOverflow is not a place that writes the codes for u.

Answer (score 0):

the below is for forming the div element for displaying select dropdown
/* Custom Select Box */

```
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
    a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    x[i].appendChild(a);
    b = document.createElement("DIV");
    b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
    for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var y, i, k, s, h;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                    s.selectedIndex = i;
                    h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                    h.setAttribute("class", "select-selected highlight-selected");
                    y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                    for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                        y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                    }
                    this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                    break;
                }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
    }
    x[i].appendChild(b);
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        closeAllSelect(this);
        this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
        this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
        var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
        y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                arrNo.push(i)
            } else {
                y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
            }
        }
    }
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

In React im displaying the select dropdown as:

```
<select className="select-selected" id={val.QuestionId} name={val.Question} onChange={props.handlers}>
                                        <option value="">Select your option</option>     
                                        {val.Options.map((options, k) => {
                                            return (
                                                <SelectInput key={k} id={options.DisplayText} options={options.DisplayText}/>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </select>
```

The problem is: 
Im using handler function for select but the UI is framing the div content instead of select. The reason for using div element instead of select is the styles cannot be applied to option tags in html. here, how can I use the div content in React to handle answers. If any example that makes the div dropdown in react and handles the validation / answers. please share. Im really worried about it